# if $0 < x <1$, How can I prove $ \ln{x} > 1- \frac{1}{x}$ without derivative or integral

Tags: trigonometry

If $0 < x <1$, how can I prove$$ \ln x > 1- \frac{1}{x}$$ without derivative or integral?

In the process of proving $$\sin x ^ {\sin x}> \cos x ^ {\cos x}$$ without calculus, I had to solve the above equation, but the idea does not come to mind.

Comment: would need a definition of $\ln x$ not involving an integral. [usual integral of $1/t$ from $1$ to $x$ would be out?]

Comment: Your requirement is odd looking at the kind of inequality you have. By the way, the original, trigonometric, inequality is also pretty weird. For example, it tells us that for $\;x=-\pi/6\;$ we have $$\left(-\frac12\right)^{-1/2}>\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)^{\sqrt3/2}$$ yet the left side is not even defined in the real numbers (in the complex there is no "bigger than" thingy). You must be much clearer with the problem's conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Take the upper bound:
$$
\ln {x} \leq x-1
$$
Apply it to $1/x$

Or

Starting from the fairly well-known,
$$1 - y \leq e^{-y}$$
Rearranging,
$$1 - e^{-y} \leq y$$
Substituting $y = \ln x$

---

For given upper bound

To prove: $lnx \leq x - 1$ for $x > 0$.
$\ln(x) < x−1$ for all $x>1$ can be done by contradiction (not required for your question). At $x = 1$ we have equality, so consider $x \in (0, 1)$. Then $0 < 1 - x < 1$. So, using a power series expansion for $ln(1 - x)$ at $1 - x$ we have:
$\ln x = \ln(1 - (1-x)) = -(1-x) - \dfrac{(1-x)^2}{2} - \dfrac{(1-x)^3}{3} - \dfrac{(1-x)^4}{4} -\cdots-\dfrac{(1-x)^n}{n}-\cdots < -(1-x) = x - 1$

Or

$y=x-1$ is the equation of the tangent to the ln curve at  $(1,0)$ and the function is concave, hence its graph is *under* the tangent.

Or

You can use $$\tag1e^x\ge 1+x,$$ which holds for all $x\in\mathbb R$

Comment: How do you know that is an upper bound? How do you know "the function" (which one?) is concave? How can you know the last inequality? I mean, how can you know all this *without differential calculus*? This would help the OP...

Comment: I don't know if you can but I think it'd be ridiculous to use power series or Taylor-Maclaurin series in an answer that requires **not to use** derivatives...

Answer (score 1):

Since every $x\in(0,1)$ can be written as $e^{-t}$ for some $t>0$, your inequality is equivalent to $-t> 1-e^t$ or to $e^t>t+1$, which follows from Bernoulli's inequality (or from the convexity of the exponential function, which can be proved through the midpoint-convexity, i.e. the AM-GM inequality, and the continuity):

$$ e^t > \left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^n \geq 1+n\cdot\frac{t}{n} = 1+t.$$